# LoadingState<Movie> conform to Equatable

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have my LoadingState defined as follows:

```
enum LoadingState<T: Codable> {
    case none
    case loading
    case success(T)
    case error(Error)
}
```

Movie is defined below:

```
struct Movie: Codable {
    let title: String
}
```

In my SwiftUI view I am trying to use the task(id) modifier as shown below:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var loadingState: LoadingState<Movie> = .none
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Perform Time Consuming Operation") {
                loadingState = .loading
            }.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
        }.task(id: loadingState) {
            
        }
    }
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Instance method 'task(id:priority:_:)' requires that 'LoadingState<Movie>' conform to 'Equatable'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It's exactly what the error message says, the function expects a value that conforms to Equatable. This is because `task(id:)` needs to compare the value to see if it has changed to the previous time `task(id:)` was called. See for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51300121/how-to-make-a-swift-enum-with-associated-values-equatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make your types conform to `Equatable`. Exactly what the error message says.

For your `Movie` type it can be autogenerated, you just have to add `Equatable` protocol name to the declaration:

```
struct Movie: Codable, Equatable { // <- here
    let title: String
}
```

For the `enum` it's a bit tricker, if you want it to work only with `T` also being `Equatable` you may declare it as

```
enum LoadingState<T: Codable & Equatable>: Equatable {
    // case … case … etc
}

// or
enum LoadingState<T>: Equatable where T: Codable, T: Equatable {
    // case … case … etc
}
```

Or, if you want `LoadingState` work with any `T`, but to conform to `Equatable` iff `T` is also `Equatable` you have to do it in extension (your original enum declaration stays):

```
extension LoadingState: Equatable where T: Equatable { }
```

---

You may also need to do something with `.error(Error)` case too, it may want to declare it as generic type and attach `Equatable` to it too, as we did with `T` above.